# sort dates in python array

Tags: python

How to sort the below array of dates on python 2.4

```
 timestamps = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30', '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-16']
```

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.4?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
sorted(timestamps, key=lambda d: map(int, d.split('-')))
```

Comment: Cool. Raises a `TypeError` in Python 3, though.

Comment: I don't have Python 3 installed, but would that be because map returns an iterable? In that case, the key function should be lambda d: tuple(map(int, d.split('-'))).

Comment: If you need the latest date in the array, you can add the `reverse=True` argument.

Answer (score 71):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in timestamps]
>>> dates.sort()
>>> sorteddates = [datetime.datetime.strftime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in dates]
>>> sorteddates
['2010-01-12', '2010-01-14', '2010-02-07', '2010-02-11', '2010-11-16', '2010-11-
22', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-26', '2010-12-02', '2010-12-13', '2011-02-04', '2011
-06-02', '2011-08-05', '2011-11-30']
```

Comment: This is the most pythonic way I think. It scales to different formats of time, unlike the accepted answer.

Comment: best answer (+1) but you probably should not call the last object `sorted` as it is also the name of a [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: How to disaccept another answer and accept this one? :)

Comment: this is most logical approach of sorting dates, if they are in string format.

Answer (score 13):

Just doing that:

```
timestamps.sort()
```

result:

```
['2010-1-12',
 '2010-1-14',
 '2010-11-16',
 '2010-11-22',
 '2010-11-23',
 '2010-11-26',
 '2010-12-02',
 '2010-12-13',
 '2010-2-07',
 '2010-2-11',
 '2011-02-04',
 '2011-06-2',
 '2011-08-05',
 '2011-11-30']
```

The order year-month-day allow such a sorting because a day changes before a month and a month changes before a year when time is passing.

It's like for a number: the unity digit (the rightmost digit) changes before the ten digit, and this latter changes before the hundred digit, when 1 is progressively added.

And there is the fact that **sort()** processes from left to right : if the characters at one precise  position  are the same in two strings to sort, it will examine the two characters in the two string at the following position to decide which one is logically preceding.

Plus the fact that **'0' < '1'** is **True**, **'1' < '2'** is **True** etc

Comment: That way, `2010-10-1` will be sorted before `2010-2-1`.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Oh yes. It only works if the numbers are zfilled(2) which is more frequently the case

Comment: and your result is wrong, because `'2010-2-07'` comes after `'2010-12-13'` , this is radix sort

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import time
>>> timestamps = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30', '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-16']
>>> timestamps.sort(key=lambda x: time.mktime(time.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d")))
>>> timestamps
['2010-1-12', '2010-1-14', '2010-2-07', '2010-2-11', '2010-11-16', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-26', '2010-12-02', '2010-12-13', '2011-02-04', '2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-11-30']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you sort them into the same format you can just call `timestamps.sort()`

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda x:x[1], sorted(map(lambda a:[map(int,a.split('-')),a], timestamps)))

['2010-1-12',
 '2010-1-14',
 '2010-2-07',
 '2010-2-11',
 '2010-11-16',
 '2010-11-22',
 '2010-11-23',
 '2010-11-26',
 '2010-12-02',
 '2010-12-13',
 '2011-02-04',
 '2011-06-2',
 '2011-08-05',
 '2011-11-30']
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort ascending dates in dd/mm/yyyy format

```
from datetime import datetime 
c_array=['07/12/2017', '30/01/2018', '31/05/2016', '30/09/2016', '30/01/2017', '31/05/2017']

sorted(c_array, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
#out: ['31/05/2016', '30/09/2016', '30/01/2017', '31/05/2017', '07/12/2017', '30/01/2018']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(sorted(list_of_strings,key=lambda x :(int(x.split('-')[0]),int(x.split('-')[1]),int(x.split('-')[2])))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 and using (my personal favorite) **comprehensions**. For dates, I would always use Python's `datetime` lib:

```
from datetime import date
timestamps = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30', '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-14']
timestamps = [date(*[int(y) for y in x.split("-")]) for x in timestamps]
sorted_timestamps = sorted(timestamps)
```