# Convert word documents to PDF, sort by date last modified before conversion, with Python?

Tags: python, pdf

There is a massive project, about 300 separate word files.

They are all organized by date last modified, and it is important they stay that way.

They need to be modified to PDF, and then combined into a single PDF, all sorted by date last modified.

Any ideas? I know of several python tools to do the conversion process, but not based on date last modified.

would greatly appreciate some assistance.

Comment: And this must be Python? It is likely much more easily done as a Bash script calling a combination of ls -t and pdfunite/pdftk/something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem could be approached by using a two dimensional array holding the name and date created then sorting( os.path.getmtime, sorted()). This may be of assistance. 
[How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)
Also sorting dates is pretty simple:
[sort dates in python array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166842/sort-dates-in-python-array)