# Is it possible to write a python program that will enable you to sort the content of a text file in python

Tags: python, excel, sorting, random, average

I have been writing a maths quiz and the program asks the students questions and then saves their score like so:

```
class_number = prompt_int_big("Before your score is saved ,are you in class 1, 2 or 3? Press the matching number")

filename = (str(class_number) + "txt")
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write("\n" + str(name) + " scored " + str(score) +  " on difficulty level " + str(level_of_difficulty) + "\n")
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
    lines.sort()

if prompt_bool("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
    for line in lines:
        print (line)
else:
    sys.exit("Thanks for taking part in the quiz, your teacher should discuss your score with you later")
```

However I have been instructed to save the last three scores to a students name and then display an average of these last three scores. This requires scores to be saved to students name. I am thinking about outsourcing this to excel however I don't know how to do this using a test file or whether a text file will even open in excel.

Here is the rest of code:

```
import random
import sys


def get_input_or_quit(prompt, quit="Q"):
    prompt += " (Press '{}' to exit) : ".format(quit)
    val = input(prompt).strip()
    if val.upper() == quit:
        sys.exit("Goodbye")
    return val

def prompt_bool(prompt):
    while True:
        val = get_input_or_quit(prompt).lower()
        if val == 'yes':
          return True
        elif val == 'no':
          return False
        else:
         print ("Invalid input '{}', please try again".format(val))


def prompt_int_small(prompt='', choices=(1,2)):
    while True:
        val = get_input_or_quit(prompt)
        try:
            val = int(val)
            if choices and val not in choices:
                raise ValueError("{} is not in {}".format(val, choices))
            return val
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
                print(
                    "Not a valid number ({}), please try again".format(e)
                    )

def prompt_int_big(prompt='', choices=(1,2,3)):
    while True:
        val = get_input_or_quit(prompt)
        try:
            val = int(val)
            if choices and val not in choices:
                raise ValueError("{} is not in {}".format(val, choices))
            return val
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
                print(
                    "Not a valid number ({}), please try again".format(e)
                    )

role = prompt_int_small("Are you a teacher or student? Press 1 if you are a student or 2 if you are a teacher")
if role == 1:
    score=0
    name=input("What is your name?")
    print ("Alright",name,"welcome to your maths quiz."
            " Remember to round all answers to 5 decimal places.")
    level_of_difficulty = prompt_int_big("What level of difficulty are you working at?\n"
                                 "Press 1 for low, 2 for intermediate "
                                    "or 3 for high\n")


    if level_of_difficulty == 3:
        ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    else:
        ops = ['+', '-', '*']

    for question_num in range(1, 11):
        if level_of_difficulty == 1:
            max_number = 10
        else:
            max_number = 20

        number_1 = random.randrange(1, max_number)
        number_2 = random.randrange(1, max_number)
        operation = random.choice(ops)

        maths = round(eval(str(number_1) + operation + str(number_2)),5)
        print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
        print ("The question is",number_1,operation,number_2)
        answer = float(input("What is your answer: "))
        if answer == maths:
            print("Correct")
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)

    if score >5:
        print("Well done you scored",score,"out of 10")
    else:
        print("Unfortunately you only scored",score,"out of 10. Better luck next time")


    class_number = prompt_int_big("Before your score is saved ,are you in class 1, 2 or 3? Press the matching number")

    filename = (str(class_number) + 'txt')
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write("\n" + str(name) + " scored " + str(score) +  " on difficulty level " + str(level_of_difficulty) + "\n")
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
        lines.sort()

    if prompt_bool("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
        for line in lines:
            print (line)
    else:
        sys.exit("Thanks for taking part in the quiz, your teacher should discuss your score with you later")
```

Comment: Please don't make us head-parse your code in order to figure out the format of your file. Also, what does the question title have to do with the task you are describing in the question? Furthermore, is file I/O the problem or is creating an adequate mapping the problem? Where should we start? TL; DR: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry I don;'t understand what your saying

Comment: I'm basically saying that your question is unclear and you should read the link I gave you.

Comment: I still don't understand after reading this comment please could you help me. You don't understand how desperate I am

Comment: Have you used SQL before? You could use a database which would store 2 tables student and scores(link using primary and foreign keys) then when asked for the average of last 3 scores get all that students scores and filter out the latest 3. I think this would be better than using excel or a txt file.

Comment: What would a solution look like

Comment: ill do some code and post it as an answer

Comment: updated my answer with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist i would create the database and have it look like the following (note viewed this using the db browser for sqlite)
[image]

Note ignore the top table the db browser auto makes that the ones you are interested in are the other 2. The way you would use this is by using the two student ids to link the tables together, each time a student is added the student id will auto increment this means that it wil be made for you and go up by 1 for each new record.

With this there would be serverall sql you want be wanting, the one shown below is the sql needed to create your tables/ clear them:

```
sql = """CREATE TABLE `tbl_Students` (
    `StudentID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `FirstName` TEXT,
    `LastName`  TEXT
         )"""
        #this is the sql that will be run
        with sqlite3.connect("studentscores.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where name=?",("tbl_Students",))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format("tbl_Students")) #if table exist delete it
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()

        #this is the sql that will be run
        sql = """CREATE TABLE `tbl_scores` (
    `StudentID` INTEGER,
    `DateOfScore`   INTEGER,
    `Score` INTEGER
        )"""
        with sqlite3.connect("studentscores.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where name=?",("tbl_scores",))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format("tbl_scores"))#if table exist delete it
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()
        self.cleardb.set("database cleared")
```

next is inserting values into the database

```
with sqlite3.connect("studentscores.db") as db:
            cursor=db.cursor()
            sql = "insert into tbl_Students (FirstName, Lastname) values (?,?)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(firstname,lastname))
            db.commit()
```

When inserting values for scores i would have the user select a student first so that you can then link the two tables (i often use a tree for this but a drop down could also be used which would be populated from using data from the database)

```
with sqlite3.connect("studentscores.db") as db:
            cursor=db.cursor()
            sql = "insert into tbl_scores (StudentID, DateOfScore, Score) values (?,?, ?)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(StudentID,nDateOfScore,nScore))
            db.commit()
```

thirdly is updating values

```
with sqlite3.connect("studentscores.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()
                sql = "update tblStudents set FirstName =?,LastName=? where StudentID=?"
                cursor.execute(sql,(FirstName,LastName,StudentID))
                db.commit()
```

lastly is deleting values

```
with sqlite3.connect("GuitarLessons.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            sql = "delete from tblStudents where StudentID = ?"
            cursor.execute(sql,(StudentID))
            db.commit()
```

i have made a simple example where you can add new students and scores and clear the database note i put them all on one form but it would probly be best to put them on different from by having a menu system they have to go through (this would include splitting your code up into different classes and changing the toplevel if using object orientated programming)
**note i have made it using object orientated programming**

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox,Treeview,Scrollbar

class test(Frame):
    'this runs when prgram first runs'
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.modefunction = 1
        """ Initialize the frame. """
        super(test,self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.student_input_frm = LabelFrame(self, width=100, height=30, text = "entering stdent details")
        self.student_input_frm.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.clear_databse_frm = LabelFrame(self, width=100, height=30, text = "clearing database")
        self.clear_databse_frm.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.score_input_frm = LabelFrame(self, width=100, height=30, text = "adding scores")
        self.score_input_frm.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        #these forms are used to group objects ogether
        self.create_GUI()

    def create_GUI(self):
        self.create_clear_datbase()
        self.create_student_input()
        self.create_score_input()

    def create_clear_datbase(self):
        self.cleardb = StringVar()
        self.cleardb.set("clearing datbase will cause all datba to be lost")
        self.recreatedb_btn = Button(self.clear_databse_frm, text = "re create database", command = self.recreatedb)
        self.recreatedb_btn.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
        self.cleardb_message_lbl = Label(self.clear_databse_frm, textvariable = self.cleardb)
        self.cleardb_message_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    def recreatedb(self):
        sql = """CREATE TABLE `tbl_Students` (
    `StudentID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `FirstName` TEXT,
    `LastName`  TEXT
         )"""
        #this is the sql that will be run
        with sqlite3.connect("studentscores.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where name=?",("tbl_Students",))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format("tbl_Students")) #if table exist delete it
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()

        #this is the sql that will be run
        sql = """CREATE TABLE `tbl_scores` (
    `StudentID` INTEGER,
    `DateOfScore`   INTEGER,
    `Score` INTEGER
        )"""
        with sqlite3.connect("studentscores.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where name=?",("tbl_scores",))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format("tbl_scores"))#if table exist delete it
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()
        self.cleardb.set("database cleared")

    def create_student_input(self):
        self.student_input = StringVar()
        self.student_input.set("click add student button to add student")

        self.nfirst_name_lbl = Label(self.student_input_frm, text = "students first name:")
        self.nfirst_name_lbl.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
        self.nfirst_name_txt = Entry(self.student_input_frm)
        self.nfirst_name_txt.grid(row = 0,column = 1)

        self.nlast_name_lbl = Label(self.student_input_frm, text = "students last name:")
        self.nlast_name_lbl.grid(row = 1,column = 0)
        self.nlast_name_txt = Entry(self.student_input_frm)
        self.nlast_name_txt.grid(row = 1,column = 1)

        self.nstudent_btn = Button(self.student_input_frm, text = "enter new student", command = self.nstudent)
        self.nstudent_btn.grid(row = 0,column = 3)
        self.nstudent_message_lbl = Label(self.student_input_frm, textvariable = self.student_input)
        self.nstudent_message_lbl.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

    def nstudent(self): #adds new record to studdent table
        firstname = self.nfirst_name_txt.get()
        lastname = self.nlast_name_txt.get()
        with sqlite3.connect("studentscores.db") as db:
            cursor=db.cursor()
            sql = "insert into tbl_Students (FirstName, Lastname) values (?,?)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(firstname,lastname))
            db.commit()
            self.student_input.set("new student added")

    def create_score_input(self):
        self.first_name_lbl = Label(self.score_input_frm, text = "students first name:")
        self.first_name_lbl.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
        self.first_name_txt = Entry(self.score_input_frm)
        self.first_name_txt.grid(row = 0,column = 1)

        self.last_name_lbl = Label(self.score_input_frm, text = "students last name:")
        self.last_name_lbl.grid(row = 1,column = 0)
        self.last_name_txt = Entry(self.score_input_frm)
        self.last_name_txt.grid(row = 1,column = 1)

        self.search_students_adding_score_btn = Button(self.score_input_frm, command = lambda : self.search_students_adding_score(),text = "search students")
        self.search_students_adding_score_btn.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.tree = Treeview(self.score_input_frm) #tree is good way of presenting reults froim sql
        self.tree["columns"] = ("StudentID","First Name","Last Name")
        self.tree.column("StudentID",width = 100)
        self.tree.column("First Name",width = 100)
        self.tree.column("Last Name", width = 100)
        self.tree.heading("StudentID",text="StudentID")
        self.tree.heading("First Name",text="First Name")
        self.tree.heading("Last Name",text="Last Name")
        self.tree["show"] = "headings"
        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.score_input_frm, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.score_input_frm, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=yscrollbar.set, xscroll=xscrollbar.set)
        yscrollbar.grid(row=3, column=4,sticky=NS)
        self.tree.grid(row=3,column=0, columnspan = 3)
        self.tree.bind("<Double-1>",lambda event :self.OnDoubleClick_input_scores(event))

    def search_students_adding_score(self):
        FirstName = self.first_name_txt.get()
        LastName = self.last_name_txt.get()
        with sqlite3.connect("studentscores.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
            sql = "select StudentID,FirstName,LastName"\
                  " from tbl_Students"\
                  " where FirstName like ?"\
                  " and LastName like ?"
            cursor.execute(sql,("%"+FirstName+"%","%"+LastName+"%",))
            StudentList = cursor.fetchall() #results of sql put into this array
        self.loadStudents_inputing_score(StudentList)

    def loadStudents_inputing_score(self,StudentList):
        for i in self.tree.get_children():
            self.tree.delete(i)

        for student in StudentList:
            self.tree.insert("" , 0,values=(student[0],student[1],student[2]))

    def OnDoubleClick_input_scores(self,event):
        curItem = self.tree.focus()
        contents =(self.tree.item(curItem))
        StudentDetails = contents['values']
        self.nStudentID = int(StudentDetails[0])
        self.score_input_message = StringVar()
        self.score_input_message.set(" ")

        self.date_score_lbl = Label(self.score_input_frm, text = "date")
        self.date_score_lbl.grid(row = 4,column = 0)
        self.date_score_txt = Entry(self.score_input_frm)
        self.date_score_txt.grid(row = 4,column = 1)

        self.score_lbl = Label(self.score_input_frm, text = "score")
        self.score_lbl.grid(row = 5,column = 0)
        self.score_txt = Entry(self.score_input_frm)
        self.score_txt.grid(row = 5,column = 1)

        self.nstudent_btn = Button(self.score_input_frm, text = "enter new score for the selected student", command = self.nscore)
        self.nstudent_btn.grid(row = 6,column = 0)
        self.date_score_lbl = Label(self.score_input_frm, textvariable = self.score_input_message)
        self.date_score_lbl.grid(row = 6,column = 1)

    def nscore(self): #adds new record intop score table the student id indicates which student that score is for
        self.nDateOfScore = self.date_score_txt.get()
        self.nScore = self.score_txt.get()
        print(self.nStudentID)
        print(self.nDateOfScore)
        with sqlite3.connect("studentscores.db") as db:
            cursor=db.cursor()
            sql = "insert into tbl_scores (StudentID, DateOfScore, Score) values (?,?, ?)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(self.nStudentID,self.nDateOfScore,self.nScore))
            db.commit()
            self.score_input_message.set("new student added")

root = Tk()
root.title("booking system")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(bg="white")
app = test(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Then to do what you wanted in your question i would have a tree view where the user enters a student name and that used in sql to get all that students scores then sort these into order and take the top 3 and average them.

To sort these dates first convert them to date times - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)
Then to sort them - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166842/sort-dates-in-python-array)