# Sorting dates in Python

Tags: python

I am saving the day and time period of some scheduled tasks in a txt in this format:

```
Monday,10:50-11:32

Friday,18:33-18:45

Sunday,17:10-17:31

Sunday,14:10-15:11

Friday,21:10-23:11
```

I am opening the txt and get the contents in a list.
How can I sort the list to get the days and the time periods in order?
Like this:

```
Monday,10:50-11:32

Friday,18:33-18:45

Friday,21:10-23:11

Sunday,14:10-15:11

Sunday,17:10-17:31
```

Comment: Convert to a `datetime` object using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime). Then you can use standard comparisons, e.g. those used by `sorted()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166842/sort-dates-in-python-array

Comment: These dates are ambiguous what week they are. You should save your dates in a different format. Don't confuse the way you want to present the date and the unambiguous representation of a date and time. It will make tasks like this far easier if you store that date [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and they change the format to this once your read the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok let's say you only have dayofweek and the timestamps. One alternative is to calculate the amount of minutes each item is (Monday 00:00 = 0 minutes and Sunday 23:59 = max minutes) and sort with that function.

The example below sorts with the first timestamp value. One comment from a fellow SO:er pointed out that this does not include the second timestamp (end-time). To include this we can add a decimal value by inverting the amount of minutes per day.

```
((int(h2)* 60 + int(m2))/24*60) # minutes divided by maximum minutes per day gives a decimal number
```

However the key here is the following code:

```
weekday[day]*24*60 + int(h1)*60 + int(m1) # gets the total minutes passed, we sort with this!
```

And of course the sort function with a join (double-break line). When you pass a key to sorted() and that key is a function the sorting will be based on the return values of that function (which is the amount of minutes).

```
'\n\n'.join(sorted(list_, key=get_min))
```

Enough text... let's jump to a full example **updated version**

```
import io

file= """Monday,10:50-11:32

Friday,18:33-18:45

Sunday,17:10-17:31

Sunday,17:10-15:11

Friday,21:10-23:11"""

list_ = [i.strip('\n') for i in io.StringIO(file).readlines() if i != "\n"]

weekday = dict(zip(["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]))

def get_min(time_str):
    day,time = time_str.split(",")
    h1, m1 = time.split('-')[0].split(":")
    h2, m2 = time.split('-')[1].split(":")
    return weekday[day]*24*60 + int(h1)*60 + int(m1) + ((int(h2)* 60 + int(m2))/24*60)

with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n\n'.join(sorted(list_, key=get_min)))
    print('\n\n'.join(sorted(list_, key=get_min)))
```

Creates "output.txt" with:

```
Monday,10:50-11:32

Friday,18:33-18:45

Friday,21:10-23:11

Sunday,17:10-15:11

Sunday,17:10-17:31
```

Comment: Instead of `key=lambda x: get_min(x)` just write `key=get_min`

Comment: your `get_min` won't sort `'Monday,09:50-11:32'` and `'Monday,09:50-11:30'`