# Python & Sorting : Sorting Elements In Order Their Subelements in an Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, datetime

I have an array and it has 4 elements and every element has 3 subelements;

```
myList = [['26.03.2019', 'Michelle', '8'], ['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '2'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '2'], ['02.04.2019', 'Micheal', '8']]
```

As you see, every elements' first subelement is a date. And I want to order these elements with their dates. So I want that output when I enter `print(myList)`;

```
[['26.03.2019', 'Michelle', '8'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '2'], ['02.04.2019', 'Micheal', '8'], ['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '2']]
```

How can I do that? Can you give me a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(myList)` would just *print your list*. You do not want to fiddle with that. What you want to do is *sort your list prior to printing*. Like so for example:

```
import datetime


myList = [['26.03.2019', 'Michelle', '8'], ['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '2'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '2'], ['02.04.2019', 'Micheal', '8']]
myList.sort(key=lambda sublist: datetime.datetime.strptime(sublist[0], "%d.%m.%Y"))

print(myList)  # -> [['26.03.2019', 'Michelle', '8'], 
               #     ['01.04.2019', 'George', '2'], 
               #     ['02.04.2019', 'Micheal', '8'], 
               #     ['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '2']]
```

Note that doing `myList.sort(..)` permanently changes your list.. If that is not what you want, you can create a new one using `sorted` as @Rakesh proposes in his answer.

---

Kudos: the code for the sorting of the dates was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166842/sort-dates-in-python-array)

Answer (score 1):

Convert string date to datetime object and then use `sorted`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
myList = [['26.03.2019', 'Michelle', '8'], ['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '2'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '2'], ['02.04.2019', 'Micheal', '8']]

print( sorted(myList, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], "%d.%m.%Y")) )
```

**Output:**

```
[['26.03.2019', 'Michelle', '8'],
 ['01.04.2019', 'George', '2'],
 ['02.04.2019', 'Micheal', '8'],
 ['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort your list on the date string, after changing it to datetime object via strptime

```
import datetime
myList = [['26.03.2019', 'Michelle', '8'], ['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '2'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '2'], ['02.04.2019', 'Micheal', '8']]

myList.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], "%d.%m.%Y"))
print(myList)
#[
#['26.03.2019', 'Michelle', '8'], 
#['01.04.2019', 'George', '2'], 
#['02.04.2019', #'Micheal', '8'], 
#['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '2']
#]
```