# Python & Sorting : Sorting Elements in a Complex Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, datetime

I have a complex array; every element has subelements and every subelement has sub-subelements. My array is;

```
myComplex=[[['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '7']], [['26.03.2019', 'Micheal', '5'], ['26.03.2019', 'Smith', '8']], [['01.04.2019', 'Jack', '11'], ['01.04.2019', 'Michelle', '2'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '9']]]
```

Let me explain this array;

The Subelement that begins with '03.04.2019'; `['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '7']`

The Subelement that begins with '26.03.2019'; `['26.03.2019', 'Micheal', '8']`, `['26.03.2019', 'Smith', '5']`

The Subelement that begins with '01.04.2019'; `['01.04.2019', 'Jack', '11']`, `['01.04.2019', 'Michelle', '2']`, `['01.04.2019', 'George', '9']`

In `myComplex` above, as you see, every subelements' first sub-subelement is a date. I want to order these subelements with their dates. So I want the output like this when I enter `print(myComplex)`;

```
[[['26.03.2019', 'Micheal', '5'], ['26.03.2019', 'Smith', '8']], [['01.04.2019', 'Jack', '11'], ['01.04.2019', 'Michelle', '2'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '9']], [['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '7']]]
```

How can I do that? Can you give me a solution for this?
I asked a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55629034/python-sorting-sorting-elements-in-order-their-subelements-in-an-array) but now I have more complex array.

Comment: Do you want to group by date?

Comment: @Rakesh yes, order should be 26.03.2019, 01.04.2019,03.04.2019

Comment: `myComplex.sort(key=lambda x: x[0][0][::-1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

myComplex=[[['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '7']], [['26.03.2019', 'Micheal', '5'], ['26.03.2019', 'Smith', '8']], [['01.04.2019', 'Jack', '11'], ['01.04.2019', 'Michelle', '2'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '9']]]
result = defaultdict(list) 
for i in myComplex:
    for j in i:
        result[j[0]].append(j)

print(result.values())
```

**Output:**

```
[[['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '7']],
 [['26.03.2019', 'Micheal', '5'], ['26.03.2019', 'Smith', '8']],
 [['01.04.2019', 'Jack', '11'],
  ['01.04.2019', 'Michelle', '2'],
  ['01.04.2019', 'George', '9']]]
```

---

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime        
from itertools import groupby, chain

myComplex=[[['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '7']], [['26.03.2019', 'Micheal', '5'], ['26.03.2019', 'Smith', '8']], [['01.04.2019', 'Jack', '11'], ['01.04.2019', 'Michelle', '2'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '9']]]
data = chain.from_iterable(myComplex)
result = [list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], "%d.%m.%Y")), lambda x: x[0])]
pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a pandas dataframe out of your array and group it after the date column. 
This dataframe you then could convert back to a "complex" array.

for reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

code snippet:

```
df.groupby("date").apply(set)
```