# Sort python array field as date string by date

Tags: python, arrays

Python JSON array as show in example

```
[{
   "id":"3",
   "creator_id":"2131xxxxxxxx",
   "lowest_price_at":"2021-01-21T09:29:38-08:00",
   "status":"published",
   "status_changed_at":"2021-02-09T23:59:34-08:00",
   "origin_domain":"us"
},
{
   "id":"5",
   "creator_id":"2131xxxxxxxx",
   "lowest_price_at":"2021-01-15T09:29:38-08:00",
   "status":"published",
   "status_changed_at":"2021-02-09T23:59:34-08:00",
   "origin_domain":"us"
},
{
   "id":"1",
   "creator_id":"2131xxxxxxxx",
   "lowest_price_at":"2021-01-5T09:29:38-08:00",
   "status":"published",
   "status_changed_at":"2021-02-09T23:59:34-08:00",
   "origin_domain":"us"
}]
```

It's contained in live_items array.
Now I need to sort that array by `status_changed_at` descending.
Meaning first item in array needs to be the one with `"id":"1"`

```
from datetime import datetime
print(sorted(live_items, key=lambda x['status_changed_at']: datetime.strptime(x['status_changed_at'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-08:00").strftime("%b %d %Y %I:%M%p")))
```

> SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant
> "=="?

This I found on the thread [sort dates in python array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166842/sort-dates-in-python-array) but I just stuck since i use first time lambda ex..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the array access in the lambda expression

```
key=lambda x['status_changed_at']: ...
```

and do

```
key=lambda x: ...
```

The array access is done later:

```
datetime.strptime(x['status_changed_at'] ...
```

For descending sorting, you also need

```
..., reverse=True)
```

Other than that, you need to rework your expression in [`strftime`](https://strftime.org/), because you have the month first and it's locale dependent. `%Y%m%d%H%M` probably sorts better.

Comment: that's driving me nuts for a very long time. Thank you. Sometimes i need to read documentation about i.e strftime before actually start using it -.-

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide the key `status_changed_at` with lambda. The first parameter represent the element itself.

It should be:

```
from datetime import datetime
res = sorted(live_items,  key=
             lambda x: 
                 datetime.strptime(x['status_changed_at'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-08:00").strftime("%b %d %Y %I:%M%p"))
```